# multiplying an input by an average

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to get an average weight on destination. So it would need to be the average * destination. The user inputs the destination say mars whose value would be 0.377. How can i get this code to work. I get that there is some error for float. How can i ammend this code.

```
    def avgMass():
        destination = input("Please enter destination: ")
        Mars = 0.377
        a, b, c, d, e,  f = [int(a) for a in input("Enter astronaut weights seperated by a 
        space: ").split()]
        weights = a, b, c, d, e,  f
        crewweight = 100
        specialistweight = 150
        available = (crewweight - a, crewweight - b, crewweight - c,
        specialistweight - d, specialistweight - e, specialistweight - f)
        sumofmass = sum(available)
        average = sumofmass / len(weights)
        destweight = average * destination
        print("Available weight for astronauts: ", available)
        print("Total available weight: ", sumofmass, "kg")
        print("Average available weight: ", average, "kg")
        print("Average available weight on destination: ", destweight)
```

Comment: "I get that there is some error for float" Exactly *what* error do you get?

Comment: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: `destweight = average * destination` isn't `destination` a string here?

Comment: **What** do you mean by `destweight = average * destination`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a Numerical operation on a string, you need to map the user input to a meaningful numerical value- there can be multiple ways of doing this. One of the easier way I would suggest is using a dictionary. sample code below OR You could Obviously just take the destination distance as User input Looking at your current code I think you want to take the planet name as input .

```
def avgMass():
    user_input = input("Please enter destination: ")
    dict_dest_mapping = {'Mars':0.377 , 'Venus':0.55}

    if user_input in dict_dest_mapping.keys():
        destination = dict_dest_mapping[user_input]


    a, b, c, d, e, f = [int(a) for a in input("Enter astronaut weights seperated by a space: ").split()]
    weights = a, b, c, d, e, f
    crewweight = 100
    specialistweight = 150
    available = (crewweight - a, crewweight - b, crewweight - c,
                 specialistweight - d, specialistweight - e, specialistweight - f)
    sumofmass = sum(available)
    average = sumofmass / len(weights)
    destweight = average * destination
    print("Available weight for astronauts: ", available)
    print("Total available weight: ", sumofmass, "kg")
    print("Average available weight: ", average, "kg")
    print("Average available weight on destination: ", destweight)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avgMass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to:

```
    def avgMass():
        destination = "Mars"
        average = 0.32
        destweight = average * destination
```

You need to write a function which prompts for a string destination and then returns the corresponding float.  (Probably by looking it up in a map.)  The function should loop until given a valid destination.

Comment: i see there are many ways around this. just so overwhelmed with it all haha. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Add a recursive function that checks `destination` till is acceptable(numeric) let's say `float`. i.e.:

```
def get_destination():
    try:
        destination = float(input("Please enter destination: "))
        return destination
    except:
        return get_destination()

def avgMass():
    destination = get_destination()
    Mars = 0.377
    a, b, c, d, e, f = [int(a) for a in input("Enter astronaut weights seperated by a space: ").split()]
    weights = a, b, c, d, e, f
    crewweight = 100
    specialistweight = 150
    available = (crewweight - a, crewweight - b, crewweight - c,
                 specialistweight - d, specialistweight - e, specialistweight - f)
    sumofmass = sum(available)
    average = sumofmass / len(weights)
    destweight = average * destination
    print("Available weight for astronauts: ", available)
    print("Total available weight: ", sumofmass, "kg")
    print("Average available weight: ", average, "kg")
    print("Average available weight on destination: ", destweight)

avgMass()
```

Comment: i see this is a similar version to another comment here. Thank you for pointing this out will definitely help :)